# Can a EV3 program run simultaneously with the Running Robot commander app?

Tags: ev3, bluetooth, commander

Is it possible to run the Robot Commander app and a program on the EV3 brick at the same time?

If so how would it be accomplished?

Answer (score 5):

No, the Robot Commander app downloads and runs a program on your EV3. If you already have a program running, it will be stopped and the program downloaded by the commander app will run instead.

Comment: That's too bad :( It'd be pretty sweet to be able to control it and also run a background program.
You sure that's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying for the past couples days to make that work, but I cannot figure it out so I would say no.