# How can I have EV3 Commander App continue running the motor when I release the slider?

Tags: ev3, commander

I'd like to control a drawing robot that I am building with EV3 Commander App.

The problem is that EV3 Commander App stops the motor as soon as I release the slider.

Is there an option with EV3 Commander App that allows me to set the speed of a motor such that I don't have to keep my finger on the slider - and keep running when I release it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commander app is very limited in it's capabilities. Unfortunately it is not possible to [control your own program with the commander app](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/can-a-ev3-program-run-simultaneously-with-the-running-robot-commander-app).

I have tried all of the built-in EV3 Commander control pads to see if any of them were suitable. The closest thing I could find to a solution would be to use the 'EV3RSTORM' control pad.

The 'Go', 'Back', 'Left' and 'Right' buttons keep all the motors turned on permanently unless you press stop of change directions. Unfortunately you won't be able to change the variable speed of the motors but you could change the fixed speed with gears.

[image]